# How to get the expected result using list comprehension

Tags: python

I have the following lists

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[a,b]
```

i need to combine both list a and b.

result should be like `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

i tried with list comprehension

```
[x for x in i for i in c]
```

output

```
[3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
```

How can i get the result as `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` using list comprehension.

Comment: You had it nearly right: `[x for i in c for x in i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
a + b
```

If you must use list comprehension:

```
In [10]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [11]: b = [4, 5, 6]

In [12]: c = [a, b]

In [13]: [j for i in c for j in i]
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
import itertools

a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]

c = list(itertools.chain(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating, use `+` to do so:

```
c = a + b
```

If you are concatenating an arbitrary number of lists, use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

list_of_lists = [a, b]
c = list(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))
```

Note that if all you need to do is iterate over the concatenation result, you can leave of the `list()` call altogether.

Do **not** use `sum()` for this; that leads to quadratic behaviour as intermediate results are built for every element summed, which takes a full loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with + operation

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = a + b # Equal [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 different ways you can do it:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[4,5,6]
>>> c=a+b
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> c=[item for l in [a, b] for item in l]
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(*[a, b]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```